# Angular 6 + Laravel 4.2

Tags: angular, laravel

I have an application that is Angular 4+ and Laravel 4.2
My Angular CLI works normally on port 4200, and Xampp on port 80. I'm using a Chrome plugin for Cross
In localhost, it works. I do any query, but my server does not work. The requests are 404
In laravel, I moved the .htaccess and the index.php out public folder. Localhost works fine. I ran an 'echo' test and it worked.
But on the server I get a 404 error
I created a folder in the htdocs of Xampp called 'server', inside it is laravel, with all the application running local
I put all this folder by FTP on my server, but the error continues.

In the routes.php file of laravel, I have this:

```
Route::controller('/', 'DashboardController');
```

In Angular, my query URL is this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com.br/sistema/server/
```

Comment: i think you need to specify a function to call in the route:
Route::controller('/', 'DashboardController@somefunction');

Comment: I think it's not necessary, because localhost works fine